# Right way to allow all access to website in robots.txt?

Tags: html, robots.txt, web-crawlers

```
user-agent: *
disallow:
```

Is this the right way to allow all access to all content of a website to crawlers in a `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The wild card `*` after user agent means it applies to all crawlers and as there is nothing defined after the `Disallow`, the entire site is free to be crawled.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to allow access to all content of your website, just don't create a *robots.txt*, or create a blank one (to avoid 404 errors).

Comment: robots.txt is still a handy file to have, especially for listing sitemap files.

Comment: I need it to declare my sitemaps...

Comment: I think managing _sitemap.xml_ can be done out of a _robots.txt_. If you need to declare your sitemap, please edit your question.

Comment: It's useful to have a robots.txt file just to prevent your server error log file from filling up with 404 requests for robots.txt!

Answer (score 3):

To use *robots.txt* and the functionality in a nutshell: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html.

As for a *sitemap.xml* / *sitemap.xml.gz* you don't need specific a *robots.txt*.
If i.e. Google is allowed (and so to see you want that, why else `Disallow` without any) to crawl the site you can give Google the exact path. (create Google account and use Webmaster Tools, it is free and imho usefull. It even has option to create *robots.txt* for you)

Anyway, still want to use the *robots.txt* and sitemap path then this could be sample:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: 
sitemap: http://name of your website/sitemap.xml
```

Be aware that *robots.txt* file is publicly available so don't use it with the intention to hide information.
A *.htaccess* file is a much more better please to hide/protect "stuff". (if there is no access on/at server level itself)